# Eval class/def/logic with one key in Python Interactive (Emacs)

Tags: python, emacs

Is there any implementation in which when you are in the middle of some function/class/, and evaluate the entire (logical!) block of code?

Basically I want to be able to evaluate:

```
import re
import os
```

and

```
if bla == 'bla':
   print 'bla'
else:
   print 'bla'
```

also

```
def bla():
    return 1
```

and finally

```
class Bla():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1 

    def bla(self):
        self.bla = 'bla'
```

Earlier I tried to do this with "mark-paragraph". This worked great in many cases (since I especially blocked code together without extra newlines in between). But I'm now looking for a better solution. I started with a function that tries to find the starting point of a code block.

I'm trying to run this function from any point:

```
(defun python-test-eval-any ()
  (interactive)
  (when (not (and transient-mark-mode mark-active))
    (move-end-of-line 1)
    (let ((start (search-backward-regexp "^[a-zA-Z0-9#]" 0 t))
          (pre (search-backward-regexp "^$" 0 t)) 
          (middle (search-forward-regexp "^$" 10000 t 1))
          (second (search-forward-regexp "^[a-zA-Z0-9#]" 10000 t 2))) 
      (previous-line)
      (right-char)
      ;; this now prints what we matched, can be used to check
      (message (buffer-substring pre (- second 1)))))
  )
```

But it still fails. I'm still sure it is possible. Does anyone have an idea how to properly evaluate any interactive python?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to cover all cases for me so far:

```
(defun new-python-get-start () 
  (interactive)
  (while (looking-at "[ ]*$")
    (next-line)
    )
  (when (not (and transient-mark-mode mark-active))
    (move-end-of-line 1)
    (search-backward-regexp "^[a-zA-Z0-9#]" 0 t)
    (when (or (looking-at "else") (looking-at "elif"))
      (search-backward-regexp "^if" 0 t)
      )
    (ignore-errors
      (previous-line)
      (while (looking-at "[a-zA-Z]")
        (previous-line)))
    (next-line) 
    )
  (point)
  )

(defun new-python-get-end ()
  (while (looking-at "^[a-zA-Z0-9#]")
    (next-line)) 
  (if (search-forward-regexp "^[a-zA-Z0-9#]" (point-max) t)
      (progn (move-beginning-of-line 1)
             (when (or (looking-at "elif") (looking-at "else"))
               (search-forward-regexp "^else" (point-max) t)
               (search-forward-regexp "^[a-zA-Z0-9#]" (point-max) t)
               (left-char 1))
             (point))
    (point-max)) 
  )

(defun new-python-get-text ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (new-python-get-start))
        (end (new-python-get-end)))
    (when (eq (point-max) end)
      (goto-char end))
    (message (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))
    ) 
  )
```

Calling `new-python-get-text` will now show the correct evaluable code logic. I personally did a kill-ring-save, such that it can be nicely printed in IPython using `%paste` (all included in a huge command).